# "Connection" HTTP header in load balancers

Tags: load-balancing, http-headers

Do load balancers remove the HTTP header indicated in the "Connection" header? As far as I know, headers indicated in the "Connection" header are not supposed to be populated further than the first hop.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends whether the load balancer is or is not a hop at the HTTP level. Routers aren't hops, right? But proxies are. If the load balancer acts like a router, it's not a hop. If it acts more like a proxy, it is. Many types of load balancers exist.

Answer (score 2):

The Connection header, or almost any other header, is not modified when passing through the load balancer.  It is necessary to pass that header to tell the backend server what to do not only between the client and load balancer, but also between the load balancer and the server.

Also to note, some *application-aware* load balancers can modify this header should you need to.